# Wildfly14 + Unable to lookup invm queue

Tags: wildfly, activemq-artemis

Unable to lookup invm queue thru ConnectionFactory

```
Hashtable<String, Object> properties = new Hashtable<>();
properties.put("connectionFactory.ConnectionFactory", "(tcp://localhost:8080)?httpUpgradeEnabled=true&retryInterval=3000&reconnectAttempts=-1&initialConnectAttempts=10&maxRetryInterval=3000&clientFailureCheckPeriod=1000");
properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory");
InitialContext jndiContext = new InitialContext(properties);
ConnectoryFactory connFactory = (ConnectionFactory) jndiContext.lookup(connectionFactory);
Connection connection = connFactory.createConnection(userName, password);
session = connection.createSession(true, javax.jms.Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

Hashtable<String, Object> properties = new Hashtable<>();
properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, factoryInitial);
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(properties);
destination = (Destination) ctx.lookup("dynamicQueues/TestQueue"); //I can't put queue name in jndi.properties

MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
producer.send(message, Message.DEFAULT_DELIVERY_MODE, Message.DEFAULT_PRIORITY, msgTTL);
if (session.getTransacted() && session.getAcknowledgeMode() == Session.SESSION_TRANSACTED) {
   session.commit();
}
```

When I execute the above code then it throws error saying that Queue "TestQueue" does not exists. I have tried with lookup queue with dynamicQueues/TestQueue and jms/TestQueue but in both cases I got same error

Can you please let me know what is wrong with this code.

Please find below Wildfly ActiveMQ Artemis configuration

```
<server name="default" persistence-enabled="true">
    <cluster password="${jboss.messaging.cluster.password:CHANGE ME!!}"/>
    <bindings-directory path="/opt/shared/messaging/live/bindings"/>
    <journal-directory path="/opt/shared/messaging/live/journal"/>
    <large-messages-directory path="/opt/shared/messaging/live/largemessages"/>
    <paging-directory path="/opt/shared/messaging/live/paging"/>
    <security-setting name="#">
        <role name="guest" send="true" consume="true" create-durable-queue="true" delete-durable-queue="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" delete-non-durable-queue="true"/>
    </security-setting>
    <address-setting name="#" dead-letter-address="jms.queue.DLQ" expiry-address="jms.queue.ExpiryQueue" redelivery-delay="60000" max-delivery-attempts="5" max-size-bytes="50485760" page-size-bytes="10485760" address-full-policy="PAGE" redistribution-delay="1000"/>
    <http-connector name="http-connector" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor"/>
    <http-connector name="http-connector-throughput" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor-throughput">
        <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
    </http-connector>
    <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0">
        <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false"/>
    </in-vm-connector>
    <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor" http-listener="default"/>
    <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor-throughput" http-listener="default">
        <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
        <param name="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
    </http-acceptor>
    <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0">
        <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false"/>
    </in-vm-acceptor>
    <broadcast-group name="bg-group1" jgroups-cluster="activemq-cluster" connectors="http-connector"/>
    <discovery-group name="dg-group1" jgroups-cluster="activemq-cluster"/>
    <cluster-connection name="my-cluster" address="jms" connector-name="http-connector" discovery-group="dg-group1"/>
    <jms-queue name="ExpiryQueue" entries="java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue"/>
    <jms-queue name="DLQ" entries="java:/jms/queue/DLQ"/>
    <jms-queue name="TestQueue" entries="java:/jms/TestQueue java:jboss/exported/jms/TestQueue"/>
    <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory" entries="java:/ConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm"/>
    <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" connectors="http-connector" ha="true" block-on-acknowledge="true" reconnect-attempts="-1"/>
    <pooled-connection-factory name="activemq-ra" entries="java:/JmsXA java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm" transaction="xa"/>
</server>
```

Comment: 1st in-vm connection factory is only useable 'locally' since the client must be in the same vm as the server. 2nd which version of wildfly are you using ? 3rd where is your "dynamicQueues/TestQueue" defined in your configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

I just want to share some links with you, for further reading.

The quickstarts are a good entry point if you start developing with wildfly.

Here you have an external client example:
https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/14.x/helloworld-jms

Here one where it everything runs inside the wildfly container:
https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/14.x/helloworld-mdb

Here you have general documentation about messaging in wildfly 14:
https://docs.wildfly.org/14/Admin_Guide.html#Messaging

Comment: using http-remoting, I am able to lookup queue. But using above configuration, how can i lookup queue. I am successfully able to lookup connection factory and create connection but not able to lookup queue

Answer (score 0):

The initial context factory you're using (i.e. `org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory`) is a client-side only JNDI implementation for use with standalone ActiveMQ Artemis. Since you are using Wildfly you should be using their JNDI implementation (i.e. `org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory`). Then you can lookup both the connection factory and the destination from the Wildfly server and you won't need to specify the connection factory URL in your code.

Also, there is no such thing as an "invm queue".

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have created client which is outside of wildfly. Also I need  to lookup activemq using url tcp://localhost:61616. So for that I need to update http-connector/http-acceptor with netty. So can you please let me know what configuration require in above wildfly activemq subsystem

Comment: Whether your client is running within Wildfly or externally on another system you should still use the Wildfly JNDI implementation. I don't understand what you mean when you say you "need to lookup activemq using url tcp://localhost:61616." Can you clarify this? That URL is not related to JNDI. It's used by the ActiveMQ Artemis client implementation.

Comment: my client code is running outside of wildfly and I need to configure netty-connector (i.e. using port tcp://61616) not http-connector. so i can access connectionfactory and queue using netty-connector(i.e. using port tcp://61616)

Comment: You can configure the connection factory on Wildfly any way you want (it can use a netty-connector, http-connector, etc.). Then you can lookup that connection factory using the Wildfly JNDI implementation. I don't see where the problem is with this approach.

Comment: As we have already developed client which lookup external artemis. Now situation is to defined connection factory, queue/topic within wildfly. Also we cannot change the client code

Comment: You don't necessarily need to change any code in your application. If the application was written in a sensible way then the JNDI configuration should be externalized in the `jndi.properties` file which you can easily change to use the Wildfly implementation. JNDI properties are meant to be externalized so the application can be portable between different providers. Did you hard-code all the JNDI environment configuration into your client?